# How to convert one object to another one using recursion. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, frontend, javascript-objects

i don't know the way so i need help please. So i have this object

```
{   
"label": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "label": "a",
            "value": "abc"
        },
        {
            "label": "b",
            "value": 123
        },
        {
            "label": "c",
            "children": [
                {
                    "label": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "d",
                            "value": "def"
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "e",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "f",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": 0,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "label": "g",
                                            "value": "ghi"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "label": "h",
                                            "value": 456
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "label": 1,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "label": "i",
                            "value": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "j",
                            "value": "abc"
                        },
                       {
                            "label": "asd",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "label": 0,
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "label": "qwe",
                                            "value": "kuracpalac"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "label": "rtz",
                                            "value": "asdasdasdasd"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

, and i need it to convert it to new object that looks like this one :

```
const obj = {
  a: "abc",
  b: 123,
  c: [
    {
      d: "def",
      e: 1,
      f: [
        {
          g: "ghi",
          h: 456
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      i: 1,
      j: "abc",
      asd: {
        qwe: "kuracpalac",
        rtz: "asdasdasdasd"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Thank you for you help :)!

Comment: You should always try to include anything you have tried in your questions so people can help nudge you in the correct direction or see where your failure of understanding is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two functions, one for getting either an array, depending on the keys, if integer values or an assigned object. The other function returns an object with a new key/value pair, either a value or a nested object structure of the children array.

```js
function assign(array) {
    return Object.assign(0 in array[0] ? [] : {}, ...array);
}

function getObject({ label, value, children }) {
    return { [label]: value || assign(children.map(getObject)) };
}

var data = { label: "root", children: [{ label: "a", value: "abc" }, { label: "b", value: 123 }, { label: "c", children: [{ label: 0, children: [{ label: "d", value: "def" }, { label: "e", value: 1 }, { label: "f", children: [{ label: 0, children: [{ label: "g", value: "ghi" }, { label: "h", value: 456 }] }] }] }, { label: 1, children: [{ label: "i", value: 1 }, { label: "j", value: "abc" }, { label: "asd", children: [{ label: 0, children: [{ label: "qwe", value: "kuracpalac" }, { label: "rtz", value: "asdasdasdasd" }] }] }] }] }] },
    result = getObject(data).root;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped!